# Find index with highest sum. Not sum of array. Sample: [11-11-11,22-22-22,33-33-33]

Tags: arrays, if-statement, indexing, sum, max

I need to find the index in an array with the highest sum. The array looks like this: [11-11-11,22-22-22]. So index [0] would equal 6. Also, if the highest sum matches another the last should be returned. I'm seeing a Max.array.length , a for/if/else statement maybe. If anyone can give me a hint I would appreciate it.

Comment: "So index [0] would equal 6" can you expand on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow something like this.

```
def get_highest_sum_and_index(arr=[])
  highest_sum = 0
  highest_sum_index = 0
  arr.each_with_index do |element, index|
    sum = element.split("").map(&:to_i).sum
    if sum >= highest_sum
      highest_sum = sum
      highest_sum_index = index
    end
  end
  return highest_sum, highest_sum_index
end

highest_sum,highest_sum_index =  get_highest_sum_and_index(["11-11-11","22-22-22","33-33-33"])
  # => highest_sum = 18
  # => highest_sum_index = 2
```

We can optimize as we want later on. This can be your starting point

Comment: wow, thanks, it's funny, I was going a totally different way. I was trying to use .replace(/\D/g,'').split("").reduce... but I am not getting that right. 
So I'm new to this and keep running into this problem. I get these chunks of code and don't know how to make them work. Am I supposed to call this somehow? like add return get_highest_sum_and_index

Comment: You use the methods in your model, and you can define it as instance methods and model functions by attaching `self` to it.  Then you need to call that method wherever you want from. You can refer http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Comment: Thanks @AmitBadhekaPykihStaff , much appreciated.